# How to create a file with its name given on command line in C++?

Tags: c++, file, command-line

I'm doing some C++ tutorials, and so far I am pretty damn good at it. However, there is one thing that perplexed and forced off the rail my knowledge acquiring, which gives me a headache.

How to create a file with its name given on the command line?

Comment: Which platform? Can you use boost?

Comment: Roman B. Why would I joke with this thing? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: ~FailedDev, Windows platform.

Comment: @DjordjeAnatasovic I would suggest either use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/program_options.html or http://tclap.sourceforge.net/. Command line parsing is tedious and error prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking about how to get a string from the command line to name the file to open?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    if(2>argc) {
        std::cout << "you must enter a filename to write to\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::ofstream fout(argv[1]); // open a file for output
    if(!fout) {
        std::cout << "error opening file \"" << argv[1] << "\"\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fout << "Hello, World!\n";
    if(!fout.good()) {
        std::cout << "error writing to the file\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse the command line parameters and use one of them as the file name for your file. see this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
    {
        /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
        printf( "usage: %s filename", argv[0] );
    }
    else 
    {
        // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
        FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

        /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
        if ( file == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Could not open file\n" );
        }
        else 
        {
            int x;
            /* read one character at a time from file, stopping at EOF, which
               indicates the end of the file.  Note that the idiom of "assign
               to a variable, check the value" used below works because
               the assignment statement evaluates to the value assigned. */
            while  ( ( x = fgetc( file ) ) != EOF )
            {
                printf( "%c", x );
            }
            fclose( file );
        }
    }
}
```

See here for more details: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html